# Simplest code to import a .gif

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm looking for the simplest code to run a .gif in my program.  The file is called "vault_ext.gif".  So far I have:

```
from tkinter import *

def vault():
    photo = PhotoImage(file="vault_ext.gif")

vault()
```

Comment: Is this a tkinter program? If so, tag your question as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import tkinter as tk
>>> root = tk.Tk()
>>> w = 500 # replace 500 with the width of your photo
>>> h = 600 # replace 600 with the height of your photo
>>> canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=w, height=h)
>>> canvas.pack()
>>> img = tk.PhotoImage(file='vault_ext.gif')
>>> img_ref = canvas.create_image(w//2, h//2, image=img)
```

That is the basic way of getting an image to display. I recommend looking for examples of `tkinter` applications that use classes so you can more easily implement interactivity. [Effbot's tkinterbook](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) is a great resource.

Let's add a binding:

```
>>> def printer(event):
...     print(event.x, event.y)
...
>>> canvas.bind("<Button-1>", printer)
```

Every time you left-click on the picture, it prints the x,y coordinates of where you clicked (coordinates start from the top left corner).

Comment: you are my hero.  this worked!  if you have an extra second, what would you do if I had a "safe keypad" as the image, and wanted the user to input four button clicks in the right order to move forward?

Comment: Take note of which pixels in your image correspond to which buttons on the keypad, then have the function that's bound to the mouse button (`printer` in my example) check the event's x and y location and compare it to the locations of the keypad buttons. If button 1 went from 100,300 down to 130,350, you'd check `if event.x in range(100,131) and event.y in range(300,351):` and then do stuff accordingly. It would be tidier if the buttons' pixel locations followed a regular pattern. Remember, coordinates start from the top left.